# What is the best way to route to different controllers in CakePHP depending on HTTP header values?

Tags: cakephp, routes, http-headers, cakephp-2.3

I'm looking for a way to route URLs to different controllers depending on the value of the HTTP 'Accept' header.

All I have found so far is the official [CakePHP documentation on routes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) but it is not very detailled.

Is this possible using route configurations or do I have to do this another way (e.g. by implementing a `DispatcherFilter` to inspect the `CakeRequest`)?

Comment: You chances of getting a proper answer will improve if you also provide some details why do you need to switch controllers based on Accept header. Generally only switching the view class and/or data format returned is necessary. The controller/action remains same.

Comment: @ADmad Don't really see why that would be necessary, tbh. But ok. Basically I want a set-up where I can seamlessly distribute responsibilities between server side and client side: e.g. letting the client handle the view creation instead of the server responding with an HTML document. I need to send different documents back in this case.

Comment: "Don't really see why that would be necessary" You are right. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @ADmad No need to apologize. No problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want a set-up where I can seamlessly distribute responsibilities
>   between server side and client side: e.g. letting the client handle
>   the view creation instead of the server responding with an HTML
>   document.

Guess you're using something like AngularJS? Well, then you expect a data format back instead of HTML I guess. So request application/json via the accept header and / or the extension. Cake can detect both and respond accordingly.

Read about JSON and XML views in the manual.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Comment: Yeah, well something similar to Angular JS but more drastic. This is a coding experiment of mine, mind you. Excellent link by the way; just what I need!